# Custom Data Generator for LSTM

Tags: keras, lstm, data-generation

Dataset: I have several .csv files with shape (no. of samples, 60,200) where number of samples  can vary.

LSTM model: I have am LSTM model accepting input of shape (60,200)
I am trying to make a data generator to fetch data from these .csv files and pass to LSTM.

But I receive a Value error:   None values not supported.

I yield 3D arrays of shape (batch size, 60 200). What can be the possible error
I am calling the function as follows:

```
model.fit_generator(gen_train,steps_per_epoch=739, validation_data=(gen_val), validation_steps=44,epochs=50)
```

where 739 is the number of .csv files for my training data and 44 is the number of .csv for validation data.

The code for data generator is as follows :

## takes input file names time,label. Each file has different no. of samples so I append the left over samples<32 of previous file with new one on each iteration.

```
def data_gen(time,label):
    print("in data generator")
    batch_size = 32
    temp_time=np.empty((0,60,200))
    temp_label=np.empty((0,1))
    while True:
        for j in range(len(time)):
        time_arr=np.loadtxt(time[j])
        time_arr=time_arr.reshape(-1,60,200)
               label_arr=np.loadtxt(label[j])
        label_arr=label_arr.reshape((-1,1))
        temp_time=np.vstack((temp_time,time_arr))
        temp_label=np.vstack((temp_label,label_arr))
        l=len(temp_time)
        i=0
        while(l>32):
            yield (temp_time[i:i+32], temp_label[i:i+32])
        i=i+32
        l=l-32
    temp_time=temp_time[i:i+l]
    temp_label=temp_label[i:i+l]
```

Comment: Can you share the generator code

Comment: I just edited my code. Please see in the question posted.